# Doctrine Listener : Modify linked entity

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I'm using a doctrine Event Listener for add an operation on an update event. When my entity is updated I want an other one changed too. The two entities are linked by a oneToMany relation but the one I changed isn't on the "right" side of the relation to cascade.

There an example of code for a better comprehension.

```
Entities\Test:
  type: entity
  entityListeners:
    Listeners\Test
  manyToOne:
    counter:
      targetEntity: Entities\Counter
      inversedBy: tests
      joinColumn:
        name: counterId
        referencedColumnName: id
        onUpdate: CASCADE

Entities\Counter:
  type: entity
  oneToMany:
    tests:
      targetEntity: Entities\Test
      mappedBy: counter
      cascade: ["persist"]
```

And my listener :

```
class Counter
{
  public function preUpdate(Test $oTest, LifecycleEventArgs $oEvent)
  {
    $oTest->getCounter()->setUpdateVar(1);
  }
}
```

And I can use $oTest->getCounter() or $oEvent->getEntity()->getCounter() and even use persist() but the counter var never change.

Anyone has an idea on how I can do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the `postUpdate` method ?

```
class Counter
{
  public function postUpdate(Test $oTest, LifecycleEventArgs $oEvent)
  {
    $oTest->getCounter()->setUpdateVar(1);
    $oEvent->getEntityManager()->flush($oTest->getCounter());
  }
}
```

From here, you'll be able to flush your associated  entity. I think it will work fine like that ;)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to persist the `Counter` entity:

```
class TestListener extends 
{
    public function preUpdate(Test $oTest, LifecycleEventArgs $oEvent)
    {
       $oTest->getCounter()->setUpdateVar(1);
       $oEvent->getEntityManager()->persist($oTest->getCounter());
    }
}
```

Comment: I already try that, without success. I have also try to use UnitOfWork functions but none of it works.